# How to check some condition on a computed column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I asked my question in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722749/change-the-value-of-computed-column-in-specific-conditions?noredirect=1#comment43858248_27722749) but it did not solved.

I have a table named `Circulation` (In library management system.) 
Column Name:- `IsReturned`,`Delay` `StartDate`,`Time` and `EndDate`

I save both `Checkin` and `Checkout` in this table in this way that there is a column named `IsReturned` that when a book checkout it is `equal` to `false` and when the book in returned to the library `checkin` it equals to `true`.

**I want to calculate the delay of a checkout too**.

My column in this table are `StartDate`,`Time` and `EndDate` (a computed column that is "StartDate" + "Time"). I want to calculated the Delay until the document not returned. (until the `IsReturned` column is false) using a computed column.

I need that if the `IsReturned` column is true , the value of Delay column should not change but if not it should update.

I use the below code to update the Delay column if `IsReturned = 0` but how can I change this code to don`t change the delay value if the`IsReturned = 1`.

```
SELECT   (DATEDIFF(minute,DATEADD(day, [Time],[StartDate]),GETDATE()))
FROM  dbo.Circulation 
WHERE Id= @Id
```

Update :

My Table is this :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Circulation](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Document_Id] [int] NULL,
[Person_Id] [int] NULL,
[Librarian_Id] [int] NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
[IsReturned] [bit] NULL,
[EndDate]  AS ([StartDate]+[Time]),
[Time] [int] NULL,
[Delay]  AS (CASE WHEN [IsReturned] = 1 THEN ******* ELSE (DATEDIFF(minute,DATEADD(day, [Time],[StartDate]),GETDATE()))
```

I think you do not understand my table yet. The EndDate is a computed column , too and it is "StartDate + Time" (that times came from c# Program in unit of minute). So if a book Checkedout from the library the StartDate and The EndDate are both have value but the IsReturned is false and when the book Checkedin , the IsReturned equals to true.
I want to calculate the "Delay" column from Computed Column so that :
1. When IsReturned = 0 (the book has been checked out) the Delay should calculate from this formula :

```
(DATEDIFF(minute,DATEADD(day, [Time],[StartDate]),GETDATE())
```

2. When IsReturned = 1 (the book has been checked in) the Delay **should not be changed.**
it means if it is zero, it should be zero but if not, the value should not change to zero.

Comment: So is Checkout an actual column? or the text of the IsReturned column?

Comment: The value of a computed column is always calculated from values contained in other columns. Thus, your requirement *not to change* the value of this column if IsReturned=1 is contradictory to the very nature of a computed column. There is no value stored in a computed column apart from the value being calculated by an expression.

Comment: @Pedram_Parsian:- first thing, when ask question, include all relevant details so people have better idea what exactly you want, and what you achieved till then and where you stuck? Better read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: include some sample data also....how you insert time in int column and then add to make computed column?

Comment: So the Time value comes from a C# program, but what does it represent? is it the time that the book was supposed to be borrowed for or the time the book was actually borrowed for? this will help us to understand the time column and the end date column.

Comment: it is unsolvable, since you have not explained what the computed column delay should be set to, when isreturned = 1. We cannot read your mind about business rules when you don't specify them. Otherwise @Piyush first reponse using the ELSE 0 should have worked fine if you just didn't want the value to be null.

Comment: I've changed my code to show how you can keep the date using a new column, this should satisfy your problem.

Comment: @Pedram_Parsian do not tell people how to vote. They can vote however they please. If they don't like your question then they can downvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it is impossible what you want, but is it really necessary that `Delay` column should be computed ?
you can make a producer like below that you can execute it every time that you need to calculate `Delay` (And also you can use if for every id not a specific):

```
CREATE PROC CalculateDelay (@Id INT)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE  dbo.Circulation
SET     [Delay] = ( DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(day, [Time], [StartDate]),
                         GETDATE()) )
WHERE   IsReturned = 0 
AND Id = @Id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking you want a computed column to update certain times, based on some bits, but not other times based on another bit.  I am not exactly sure the best way to accomplish this, but I think you can solve your issue in an easier way.

Instead of CheckIn, CheckOut and IsReturned flags/bits, why not just have a CheckedInOn, CheckedOutOn and ReturnedOn fields that are DateTime2/DateTimeOffset and nullable.  Fields are set to the current date and time when the corresponding action happens and are null otherwise.  This way you can easily tell the status of an item (checked in or checked out) and the delta's are super straight forward.

It also seems that Checked In and Returned may be redundant as it seems to me that the book is checked in when it is returned, although I may just not be understanding your vernacular.

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE statement, to calculate only if `IsReturned = 0`.
This is sample code

```
SELECT  CASE 
          WHEN IsReturned = 0 THEN 
             (DATEDIFF(minute,DATEADD(day, [Time],[StartDate]),GETDATE()))
          ELSE 0
        END as Delay            
FROM  dbo.Circulation 
WHERE Id= @Id
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: I do not need to update them. I want to create the computed column "Delay".

Comment: I modified the answer, Use CASE

Comment: Thanks, but I know these codes. I want to 1. Use this in a Computed formula not in a select and 2. If is returned equals zero, select the last delay not zero.

Comment: You probably need to make a good example of the table data, the parameters you are passing to the function, and what you expect to be output, because it's hard to understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: @Pedram_Parsian:- when you ask question, it is never mentioned that you need computed column

Answer (score 0):

Lets make some test data:

```
DECLARE @Circulation TABLE
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Document_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Person_Id] [int] NULL,
    [Librarian_Id] [int] NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsReturned] [bit] NULL,
    [EndDate]  AS ([StartDate]+[Time]),
    [LastUpdatedDate] DATETIME,
    [Time] [int] NULL,
    [Delay]  AS 
        (CASE WHEN [IsReturned] = 1 
         THEN DATEDIFF(minute,DATEADD(day, [Time],[StartDate]), LastUpdatedDate) 
         ELSE DATEDIFF(minute,DATEADD(day, [Time],[StartDate]), GETDATE()) 
         END)
)
```

I've included a new column, LastUpdatedDate which contains when the record was last modified, we'll use this in the computed column DELAY to get the old value.

```
INSERT INTO @Circulation
( Document_Id, Person_Id, Librarian_Id, StartDate, IsReturned, Time, LastUpdatedDate )
VALUES
( 1, 1, 1, '01/01/2014', 1, 30, '01/15/2014' ),
( 2, 1, 1, GETDATE(), 0, 30, GETDATE() );

SELECT
    Id,
    Document_Id,
    Person_Id,
    Librarian_Id,
    StartDate,
    IsReturned,
    EndDate,
    Time,
    Delay
FROM @Circulation
```

Here is the output:

```
Id  Document_Id Person_Id   Librarian_Id    StartDate   IsReturned  EndDate Time    Delay
1   1   1   1   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 0   2014-01-31 00:00:00.000 30  -30240
2   2   1   1   2015-01-05 10:10:54.627 1   2015-02-04 10:10:54.627 30  -43200
```

Comment: Ok, this was your table and computed column, I put in an else statement to make delay = 0 for now, but the real question that you have still not explained is what do you want delay to be when isreturned = 1.